# Does the representation ring functor preserve limits?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

If I have a diagram of groups $\{H_J\}$ and let $G$ be the limit of that diagram, how well does the representation ring functor "preserve the limit", IE: If I have $\lim_{J} H_J = G$ is it true that $\text{colim}_J R(H_J) = R(G)$? Does it depend on the groups involved?

Comment: Have you considered the product of two groups?

Comment: The representation ring is the shadow of a contravariant functor $G \mapsto \text{Hom}(G, \text{Vect})$, so the natural thing to ask it to preserve is colimits (which should be sent to limits), not limits.